# My for-loop is getting skipped, even though the debugger says it shouldn't

Tags: c++, for-loop, deserialization

Somehow, my for-loop (the first one) keeps getting skipped. even after stepping through it with the debugger, i cannot figure out why.

```
Grid AssetManager::deserializeGrid(std::string const& filename)
{
    std::ifstream rf(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!rf)
        std::cout << "Cannot open file!" << std::endl;
    //reading size of grid
    int gx, gy;
    rf.read((char*)&gx, sizeof(int));
    rf.read((char*)&gy, sizeof(int));
    Grid rGrid(gx, gy);
    for (int x = 0; x < gx; x++) 
    {
        //Deserializing code here
    }
    rf.close();
    if (!rf.good())
        std::cout << "Error occurred at reading time!" << std::endl;
    return rGrid;
}
```

I'm trying to read a saved file here.

While debugging, I see that `gx` and `gy` are succesfully read and have a value of `4`. Somehow though, the for-loop gets skipped and it jumps straight to the return statement.
**Edit:**
I've added 3 couts: one immediately infront of the declaration of `rGrid`, one directly after and one before the `return` statement. Only the first gives me an output (verifying that `gx` and `gy` are indeed `4`). The other two are also getting skipped. It jumps from `rGrid` directly to the `return` statement. In the constructor of `rGrid`, a `2d vector` of the size `gx, gy` gets created, nothing else (I've also checked this and it works without error).

Comment: it smells like an optimzed away issue confusng the debugger, i would put trace couts into the code to be sure you are getting the gx and gy valurs you expect and that the loops are not being entered. I also trust that this is the real code

Comment: i've added 3 couts: one immediately infront of the declaration of rGrid, one directly after and one before the return statement. Only the first gives me an output (verifying that gx and gy are indeed 4). The other t2o are also getting skipped. It jumps from rGrid directly to the return statement. In the constructor of rGrid, a 2d vector of the size gx, gy gets created, nothing else (I've also checked this and it works without error).

Comment: @Lorekp Use [edit] for updating your code and the information. Don't describe your attempts and changes in comments. BTW ignoring results of I/O functions is a bad practice.

Comment: add at least som asserts to verify you get the values you expect. e.g.  assert( gx > 0 ); you have absolutely no error handling.

Comment: Also you have 3 for-loops and it's unclear which one are you talking about until the last sentence. You seem to talk about the first one, hence the two other are irrelevant and can be removed in favor of a [mcve].

Comment: Linking an outdated version of the Grid class can do that.  If the old definition had more members then local variables (like gx and gy) get overwritten when the Grid class constructor executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer (kinda?). I realized that VisualStudio skipped all of the code (when debugging) and jumped to the return statement without actually returning anything and then going back to finish the code. So it only seemed to skip code but it really wasn't. I feel quite stupid not realising this for way too long. I don't know why VisualStudio is doing this (not only on my PC), but hey - at least it's working now.